# Error in retrieving metric values for SQL server data from AZURE

Tags: json, rest, azure, azure-sql-database

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription Id}/resourceGroups/{Resource Group}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{servername}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2017-05-01-preview&$filter=(name.value eq 'dtu_consumption_percent' ) and startTime eq 2017-09-10 and endTime eq 2017-09-11 and timeGrain eq duration'PT1H'
```

The above is the url I am passing to get the data for sql server metrics

The response i am getting is :

```
{
"cost": 0,
"timespan": "2017-09-12T03:56:27Z/2017-09-12T04:56:27Z",
"interval": "PT1M",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "/subscriptions/{subscription Id}/resourceGroups/{Resource Group}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{server name}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/dtu_consumption_percent",
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
        "name": {
            "value": "dtu_consumption_percent",
            "localizedValue": "DTU percentage"
        },
        "unit": "Percent",
        "timeseries": []
    }
]}
```

There is no data in time series.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

If I do not specify the filters, the  `dtu_consumption_percent` (default metric) can be returned when I use " 2017-05-01-preview" as the API version.

[image]

Data of timeseries:

[image]

If I specify the filters as yours and use " 2017-05-01-preview" as the API version, I get 400 error.

[image]

Under “Retrieve Metric Values” section in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough#retrieve-metric-values), I find:

> **Note**
>
> To retrieve metric values using the Azure Monitor REST API, use "2016-06-01" as the API version.

You can try to use "2016-06-01" as the API version to retrieve metric values.

[image]

Comment: `{
    "value": [
        {
            "data": [],
            "id": "/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/{resource group name}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{servername}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/dtu_consumption_percent",
            "name": {
                "value": "dtu_consumption_percent",
                "localizedValue": "DTU percentage"
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
            "unit": "3"
        }
    ]}`  **Getting response like this when executed no data is there** @Fred

Comment: If you do not specify filters, can you get data in response?

Comment: No if i don't specify the filters i am getting nothing in data array. Is there something to be done in azure portal to get the data.@Fred

Comment: Hey @PranayDas were you able to resolve this? I have the exact same issue.